# add values to mysql database using php on ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, post, mysqli

n00b learning php from a book.

I'm trying to add data to a database called adv_php.  I'm using the following snippet of code in the page that's receiving the data from the post:

```
    <?php
    $dbc = mysqli_connect('host', 'name', 'password', 'adv_php');

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connec to MySQL" . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $parent_id = $_POST['parent_id'];
    $task = $_POST['task'];

    // Add the task to the database.
    $q = "INSERT INTO (parent_id, task) tasks VALUES ($parent_id,'$task')";
    mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    ?>
```

I know this code connects to the database elsewhere as I can retrieve info from the database.  With this page, I don't get an error, I just get a blank page, and nothing is added to the database  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: what happens if you do `if (!mysqli_query($dbc, $q)) { echo "problems!" }`

Comment: Try to echo $q,ie your query string and try inserting into database via msql.

Comment: Your code is wide open to sql injections. Sanitize input from `$_POST`s and use **[prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is wrong...Change it ...

```
$q = "INSERT INTO  tasks(parent_id, task) VALUES ($parent_id,'$task')";
```

Answer (score 0):

you misplaced table_name, use below query

```
$q = "INSERT INTO tasks (parent_id, task)  VALUES ($parent_id,'$task')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your insert statement is wrong
Try this

```
       $q = "INSERT INTO tasks (parent_id, task) VALUES ($parent_id,'$task')";
```